# jQuery drag and drop in outside div only

Tags: jquery, draggable, droppable

I nearly have the solution thanks to this question: [Draggable revert if outside this div and inside of other draggables (using both invalid and valid revert options)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6071409/draggable-revert-if-outside-this-div-and-inside-of-other-draggables-using-both/6087928#6087928)

I have amended the code in jsfiddle here http://jsfiddle.net/phoebebright/jcRN7/1/ to demonstrate what I want to do showing the outside div where items are droppable and an inside div where they are not, easier to demonstrate than to explain!

How can I stop a div being dropped on a div inside a div which is droppable?

Comment: could you rephrase your question please? maybe it's just me but I didn't understand what you want to achieve.

Comment: have you looked at the jsfiddle example, a lot easier to show than explain!

Comment: it looks like the jsfiddle works how you want it to...

Comment: my problem is I want it to stop me dropping in the red area but as the red div is on top of the grey div it is still accepting the drop.

Comment: there is no red div in here http://jsfiddle.net/9ydjY/

Comment: aghh - I forked it but it hasn't saved.  Just a sec...

Comment: updated link, now it might make sense!

Comment: this is the link you gave us: http://jsfiddle.net/9ydjY/ please check if its the right one :)

Comment: I've got to go now but if you edit your question with the right info somebody else will help you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
$('.drop').droppable({
    tolerance: 'fit',
});

$('.drag').draggable({
    revert: 'invalid',
    stop: function() {
        $(this).draggable('option', 'revert', 'invalid');
    }
});

$('.drag').droppable({
    greedy: true,
    tolerance: 'touch',
    drop: function(event, ui) {
        ui.draggable.draggable('option', 'revert', true);
    }
});
```

Try adding this:

```
$('#nogo').droppable({
    greedy: true,
    drop: function(event,ui){
        ui.draggable.draggable('option','revert',true);
    }
});
```

Comment: Yes!  Thank you for sorting that out. (and is jsfiddle great).