# jqueryui resizeable and draggable element is covered

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-ui, jquery-ui-draggable, jquery-ui-resizable

I have two elements which are draggable and resizeable. They are aline horizontally.
My problem is when I attempted to resize the first element at the top, the second element position below will automatically cover the first element.

Below is the style:

```
<style>
    #request-grid { width: 500px; min-height: 200px; margin: 10px; padding: 0.5em;}
    #bb-clist { width: 500px; min-height: 200px; margin: 10px; padding: 0.5em;}
    .ui-resizable-helper { border: 2px dotted #00F; }
</style>
```

Below is the jqueryui code:

```
$( "#request-grid" ).draggable({containment: "#content", scroll: true, stack: "#content div" });
$( "#bb-clist" ).draggable({containment: "#content", scroll:true, stack: "#content div"});

$( "#request-grid" ).resizable({
helper: "ui-resizable-helper",  containment: "#content"
});

$( "#bb-clist" ).resizable({
helper: "ui-resizable-helper", containment: "#content"
});
```

Below is the html element:

```
<div id="request-grid" class="ui-widget-content">
</div>

<div id="bb-clist" class="ui-widget-content">
</div>
```

How will I solve this problem without the other element covering/overlapping the other element when resizing.

Thanks.

Comment: demo: http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/UNWH7/1/

Comment: @ArunPJohny Can you please point me what changes you made? I cannot seem to figure out. thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## **HTML**

```
<div>
    <div id="request-grid"></div>
    <br/>
    <div id="bb-clist"></div>
</div>
```

## **CSS**

```
#request-grid {
    height:100px;
    width: 200px;
    min-height: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 0.5em;
    background-color:pink;
}
#bb-clist {
    height:100px;
    width: 200px;
    min-height: 100px;
    margin: 10px;
    padding: 0.5em;
    background-color:blue;
}
.ui-resizable-helper {
    border: 2px dotted #00F;
}
```

## **jQuery**

```
$(document).ready(function () {

    $("#request-grid").draggable({
        containment: "#document",
        scroll: false,
        stack: "#content div"
    });
    $("#bb-clist").draggable({
        containment: "#document",
        scroll: false,
        stack: "#content div"
    });

    $("#request-grid").resizable({
        helper: "ui-resizable-helper",
        containment: "document",
        resize: function (event, ui) {
            var height = (ui.size.height + 'px');
            $('#bb-clist').css('posotion', 'absolute').css('top', height);
        },
        stop: function (event, ui) {
            var h2 = (ui.size.height);
            if (h2 < 200) {
                h2 = 100; // set default min-height if re-sized less than min-height.
            }
            $('#bb-clist').css('posotion', 'absolute').css('top', h2);
        }

    });

    $("#bb-clist").resizable({
        helper: "ui-resizable-helper",
        containment: "document"
    });
});
```

**Working Demo** http://jsfiddle.net/cse_tushar/qkKV6/

Answer (score 0):

You can use a z-index value to overcome the overlapping issue.

simply put a higher z-index value to your resizable element like,

```
#ResizableElement
{
  z-index: 10;    //default is 1
}
```

an element with higher z-index value will always overlap other element.
you can also set a z-index value to your draggable element which will work too.

```
$("#request-grid").draggable({ zIndex: 10 });
```

Comment: both elemets are resizeable and draggable will it work? I assume both of them will have the same zIndex.

Comment: i think that case might not work, i am not sure. i could'nt able to edit my response due to time shortage but i guess you have find the solution :)

Answer (score 0):

I was able to solve the problem using the solutions from these questions [Restrict jQuery draggable items from overlapping/colliding with sibling elements](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11452185/restrict-jquery-draggable-items-from-overlapping-colliding-with-sibling-elements)
 and [Draggable revert if outside this div and inside of other draggables (using both invalid and valid revert options)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6071409/draggable-revert-if-outside-this-div-and-inside-of-other-draggables-using-both/6087928#6087928)

I was not using the term collision when searching my problem at first.

Comment: that is good if it worked for you. please accept a response which worked for you so others can take benefit from it.