# jQuery UI Draggable revert with helper

Tags: jquery-ui, drag-and-drop

This is basically a followup question to this, as it is not encouraged to ask further questions in the comments:
[Draggable revert if outside this div and inside of other draggables (using both invalid and valid revert options)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6071409/draggable-revert-if-outside-this-div-and-inside-of-other-draggables-using-both)

This solution works rather well even though my use case is not exactly the same. There is just one small visual thing that bothers me. I have rather large draggable objects, so I am using a helper for it. No matter if the drop is valid or not, the helper still has a revert animation on it:
If it is an invalid drop, the helper moves to the original position before it fades away, which is fine.
But if it is a valid drop it does the same whereas the original gets moved to the valid position. Any ideas how I could prevent this.

Here a short snippet of the helper definition:

```
helper: function() {
    var jqThis = jQuery(this);
    var helper = jQuery('<div class="helper"/>');
    helper.text(jqThis.text().substr(0, 100));
    helper.css('width', jqThis.css('width'));
    return helper;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I just figured it out: I have to set the option back to "invalid" if it is a valid drop.

```
if (invalidDrop) {
    drag.draggable('option','revert',true);
} else {
    drag.draggable('option','revert','invalid');
}
```